# angular 2 test URL differentiates from web API URL

Tags: angular, unit-testing, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an angular-cli project, embedded in visual studio 2017. By running vs project the angular project is being served and everything works.

then when I want to test the angular project with `ng test`, it will be served on `http://localhost:9876` but API is unavailable on this URL.

Web API URL is `http://localhost:42339/` . and test fails because request goes to `http://localhost:9876`. I changed the service URLs

```
  getTagData(): Observable<any> {

     return this.adminBaseService.get(`http://localhost:42339/api/admin/Tags/GetTags`);
 }
```

but it makes calls to `http://localhost:9876`

Any help?

Comment: I think you should define route in angular project. this url is for backend. you need define a component and service for http. and use this service in component. then define a route for the component.

Comment: I have services for components and call backend through component, then service  and then c# api @mohammad-ali

Comment: Any solution to this problem?